# Create nested dictionary from file column and row headers

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, nested, mapping

I have a csv file where I want to query results based on the first row and first column. Given a csv that looks like:

```
subj_id, Sample1, Sample2, Sample3
XXX, 1, 2, 3
YYY, 4, 5, 6
ZZZ, 7, 8, 9
```

I would like to use the `subj_id` and `SampleN` to query the value. For example:

```
dct['XXX']['Sample1'] = 1, dct['YYY']['Sample2'] = 5
```

I have tried using `csv.DictReader`, but without success. How can I create a dictionary like the above? (Note: I am using python 3.6, as I see that DictReader is slightly different depending on the python version.)

My attempt was based on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31600296/creating-nested-dict-using-csv-dictreader/31600449#31600449), where the start was:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

dct = defaultdict(dict)

with open('toy_out_test_results.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    for row in csv.DictReader(csv_file, fieldnames=['subj_id','Sample1','Sample2','Sample3']):
        dct[row['subj_id']][row['???']] =
```

but I ran into a roadblock here.

Comment: Sorry about that. I added my minimal example, which I couldn't even flesh out.

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect. Is the whitespace in your CSV intentional or do you want to trim all the fields?

Comment: Ah, not intentional at all. My actual csv doesn't have it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a dictionary from a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14091387/creating-a-dictionary-from-a-csv-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the row dictionary to the `dct` dict based on the `row['subj_id']` value which you can pop out of the row:

```
import csv

dct = {}

with open('toy_out_test_results.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    for row in csv.DictReader(csv_file):
        dct[row.pop('subj_id')] = row

print(dct['XXX']['Sample1']) # => '1'
```

This assumes a CSV without extra whitespace:

```
subj_id,Sample1,Sample2,Sample3
XXX,1,2,3
YYY,4,5,6
ZZZ,7,8,9
```

Beware that duplicate `subj_id`s will be overwritten with the last seen.

Comment: Ah, now I see what I was missing. Thank you!